# Is that possible to read only and auto increment specific SharePoint fields using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, javascript

Any JavaScript/jQuery code to make SharePoint list column read only and auto increment like ID_17_1001.

NB:

Not all the item but a specific field

Answer (score 1):

I think you could custom list form by JavaScript/jQuery with JSOM/rest api to pre-init the field value and disable it.

Sample script

```
$( "input" ).val( "someValue" );
$( "input" ).prop( "disabled", true);
```

Or, create a workflow for this.

One thread for your reference.

http://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-number-field-in-a-sharepoint-list/